# How to retrieve particular string from a text kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, text, getvalue

I am getting the scan result in a string like ---

DriverId=60cb1daa20056c0c92ebe457,Amount=10.0

I want to retrive driver id and amount from this string.
How can I retrive?
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your overall format. Basic operations like substrings as suggested by @iLoveYou3000 can work fine if you really have this fixed format.

If the keys are dynamic, or could be changed in the future, you could also use more general approaches, for instance using `split()`:

```kotlin
val attributeStrings = input.split(",")
val attributesMap = attributeStrings.map { it.split("=") }.associate { it[0] to it[1] }

val driverId = attributesMap["DriverId"]
val amount = attributesMap["Amount"].toDouble() // or .toBigDecimal()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68034391/how-to-update-progress-of-seekbar-from-an-adapter-at-particular-position   can u please look at this question too?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the possible ways that I could think of.

```kotlin
val driverID= str.substringAfter("DriverId=", "").substringBefore(",", "")
val amount = str.substringAfter("Amount=", "")
```